# indexing an array

Tags: python

I find myself frequently making indexed lists from flat ones in Python. This is such a common task that I was wondering if there's a standard utility that I should be using for it.

The context is this: given an array, I need to create a dict of smaller arrays using some key for grouping.

e.g:
`["Andy","Alice","Bob","Beth","Charlie"]` becomes
`{"A":["Andy","Alice"],"B":["Bob","Beth"],"C":["Charlie"]}`

My solution looks like this:

```
def make_index(data,key,value=lambda x:x):
    d={}
    for item in data:
        k = key(item)
        v = value(item)
        try: d[k].append(v)
        except KeyError: d[k]=[v]
    return d
```

It's simple and all, but am I reinventing something that is implemented better elsewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the same a little simpler with a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def make_index(data,key,value=lambda x:x):
    d=defaultdict(list)
    for item in data:
        d[key(item)].append(value(item))
    return d
```

Using a `defaultdict` is faster than using `.setdefault()`, which would be the other option.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: it's the sorting you do that kills it.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why the `itertools` answer was deleted, but I was writing one myself:

```
from itertools import groupby
def make_index(data, key = lambda x: x[0]):
    return {key: list(gr) for key, gr in 
        groupby(sorted(data, key=key), key=key)}

In [3]: make_index(["Andy","Alice","Bob","Beth","Charlie"])
Out[3]: {'A': ['Andy', 'Alice'], 'B': ['Bob', 'Beth'], 'C': ['Charlie']}

In [4]: make_index(["Andy","Alice","Bob","Beth","Charlie"], key=lambda x: len(x))
Out[4]: {3: ['Bob'], 4: ['Andy', 'Beth'], 5: ['Alice'], 7: ['Charlie']}
```

Comment: This is certainly a more interesting answer, but it appears to take about twice as much time as Martijn's version, probably because it's mult-step transform.

Comment: @tylerl Yeah, Martjijn's version doesn't need to sort the list.